# Is it possible to `git squash` multiple branches into a single branch?

Tags: git, git-merge

If I have multiple feature branches in git, is there a way to "merge-squash" them together before merging a single branch upstream?

```
                                                   master
                                                     /
feature/user-groups     \                           /
feature/web-security     > feature/user-security   /
bugfix/country-codes    /
bugfix/trademark-year  /
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick one of the existing branches, say feature/user-groups, and fork a new branch from it:

```
git checkout feature/user-groups
git checkout -b feature/user-security
```

Now, merge the other three branches:

```
git merge feature/web-security bugfix/country-codes bugfix/trademark-year
```

This produces a single commit on the feature/user-security branch, whose parents lead to the four original branches.